# Get review snippets from Tripadvisor Content API (for many hotels)

Tags: api, tripadvisor

I have read on Google groups forum (and elsewhere), that I can get the latest 3 snippets from Content API. Is that still true?

The latest answers at Google groups about snippets are from 2016. The T&C https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/terms-and-conditions/ and this page https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/ suggest, that I can get 3 reviews. But API Description https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/description/ does not say anything about snippets, and the API is not returning the snippets (I tried hotel Copacabana, and others http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/location/151381?key=...).

I know of self-service widgets (Review snippets widget) but I need bulk data - snippets for many hotels.

Thank You.

Barbora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a response from TripAdvisor developer:

"No, since December 2016 3 review snippets has been removed from the content API. The API description is up to date. The terms and conditions need updating, sorry about that."

....

So, maybe I will try to use self-service widgets. One per each hotel.